# Xamarin Notification Push TodoItemManager

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification

I am following this guide: [Xamarin Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/push-notifications/azure/)

And in this code:

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
    {
        Log.Verbose("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Registered: " + registrationId);
        RegistrationID = registrationId;

        var push = TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush();

        MainActivity.CurrentActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => Register(push, null));
    }
```

Visual studio say me he dont found `TodoItemManager` class.
I've done it again and always got this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TodoItemManager is a class they created for the sample code but it seems they indicate so anywhere. I get to know this since I followed this same sample time ago. This is the class used to communicate with the Azure Hub for a TodoItem entity.

If you want the whole project which already has this class included just download it here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoAzurePush

**Update (11/2019)**

The above link is broken. Thanks @vnwonah for the comment.
Many things have changed in terms of Push notifications in the mobile world and I imagine that was the reason the repo was taken down.

Even though this is not part of the original question, here's the link for the new Xamarin Sample Repo about how to deal with Push Notifications:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/AzureNotificationHub

Hope it helps.

Comment: Broken Link now